# Защита apache от ддос атак

Tags: apache, защита, ddos

Можно ли поставить защиту на apache?

Apache поставлен на домашнем компьютере. Ддосом забивается трафик сайта и он перестает работать, как это прекратить?

mod_security пробовал ставь не ставится после указания пути `LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so` перестает запуться

Comment: Поставьте nginx, будет меньше проблем. У меня есть софт, который ложит apache, за все время поиска dos утилит я не нашел ни одной работающей для nginx. Одно дело ваш сервер, а другое трафик. Это у вас сеть слабая

Comment: На этом сервере крутится рабочий Web-сайт или Apache нужен только для разработки и не должен вещать во вне?

Comment: А чем софт дос атак для `apache` будет отличаться от `nginx`? дос это ведь просто запросы на сервер...

Comment: Почитайте про эти 2 веб-серверы на хабре и вы поймете в чем разница

Comment: По apache на хабре 82 публикации, по nginx 199 предлагаете всем заинтересовавшимся их все перебирать? :)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/267721/

Comment: Диагонально прочитал пост и там нет сравнения в стойкости перед дос атаками. Но разница есть -- пока читал другую статью в комментах была ссылка на другой коммент, в котором рассказывалось, что nginx кеширует какие-то запросы, благодаря чему более стоек к атаке, чем apache